# How can I add empty spaces between values to a vba array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I create an array in vba by looping through cells in a sheet (originalWS). So let's say cells (2,5) to (2,12) have the following:

```
(2,5)Item
(3,5)Type 
(4,5)Nominal Diameter
(5,5)Lead
.
.
.
(12,5)For Use with End Blocks
```

Thus, when I loop with the code below I get an array that looks like this:

[Item,Type,Nominal Diameter,Lead,...,For Use with End Blocks].

However, I would like to add two empty spaces between each value in my array. so that it looks like this:

[Item,"","",Type,"","",Nominal Diameter,"","",Lead,"","",...,For Use with End Blocks,"",""]

```
ReDim propertyArr(1, lastRow)
For i = 1 To lastRow
    propertyArr(1, i) = originalWS.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value
    Debug.Print propertyArr(1, i)
Next
```

I have tried to loop to by the final total size of the array so (lastRow*3) and step forward by 3.  However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how I would reset my orginalWS.cells(i,5) values so that they are consecutive.

In other words, when I loop stepping by 3 my values would be:

```
propertyArr(1,1) = originalWS.Cells(2,5).value
propertyArr(1,4) = originalWS.cells(5,5).value
propertyArr(1,7) = originalWS.cells(8,5).value
```

How can I loop so that I store values in my array every 2 places, while I get the values from a consecutive list in a sheet.

Can I do this without having to add extra empty row
 a way to add two empty spaces between each value within my original loop without having to add extra empty rows?

Or, can I add the two empty spaces between each value after I created my array the first time?

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick,

```
Dim lRowNo As Long

lRowNo = lastRow * 3
ReDim propertyArr(1, lRowNo)

For i = 1 To lRowNo 
    If i Mod 3 = 1 Then
        propertyArr(1, i) = originalWS.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value
    Else
        propertyArr(1, i) = ""
    End If
    Debug.Print propertyArr(1, i)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments.............I will update my post as per your instructions later today.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however I still have a problem with how I store the values from the cells. I have edited my comment so that I make my problem a bit more clear. Let me know if you have other questions. Thank you! @PaulFrancis

Comment: @PaulFrancis  I actually just figured it out.  It was all about updating my cell value correctly.  I posted the loop below.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim propertyArr(), lastRow As Long
    Dim originalWS As Worksheet
    Set originalWS = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = 5
    ReDim propertyArr(1, 2 * lastRow)
    For i = 1 To 2 * lastRow Step 2
        propertyArr(1, i) = originalWS.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value
        propertyArr(1, i + 1) = ""
        Debug.Print propertyArr(1, i)
    Next
End Sub
```

**UNTESTED**

Comment: Gary, I tested this, it is optimized than my solution. I think it might need `3 * lastRow` as for every element it needs two more. Also, it needs `propertyArr(1, i + 2) = ""` followed by `propertyArr(1, i + 1) = ""`. As the OP needed two blanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also unroll the loop a bit to do this a bit more efficiently. Note that for each iteration, `i` isn't incremented by `1`, but by `3`.

```
Public Sub test()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = 6

    Dim lastIndex As Long
    lastIndex = lastRow * 3

    ReDim propertyArr(1 To lastIndex)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastIndex Step 3
        propertyArr(i) = CInt(i / 3)
        propertyArr(i + 1) = vbNullString
        propertyArr(i + 2) = vbNullString
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: "More efficiently" as in a couple fewer lines of code? I'm assuming you're not referring to any vanishingly tiny, hypothetical performance gains... That would be silly, right? Anyhow, this is probably how I'd do it.

Comment: It depends on the size of the array @Jean-FrançoisCorbett. If it's a large number of iterations, this method could cut that number by a factor of 3.

Comment: (Um, what?) How large is large? I just tested your and @PaulFrancis's codes. There is indeed a factor of ~3. That amounts to a whopping 0.02 seconds difference for `lastRow = 32768`. For higher values of `lastrow`, your code overflows so that's the maximum possible gain :-)  Change `CInt` to `CLng` and you're all set. For `lastRow = 1 million` you gain about half a second. For anything below 1000, the difference is too small to measure using `Timer`. So, that's how large.

Comment: Can't ask for perfection from example code written in about 60 seconds. =;)-

Answer (score 1):

Or without loops

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(1)
propertyarr = Join(Application.Transpose(ws.Range("E1:E5")), ","""","""",")
```

to put back into array

```
propertyarr = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(ws.Range("E1:E5")), ",,,"), ",")
```

Comment: That is good. Just a small concern. So this would be cloaser to what the OP wantes I think? `propertyarr = Join(Application.Transpose(ws.Range("E1:E5")), ","""","""",") & ","""","""""`. Also, should a `SPLIT` follow the `JOIN` to get an Array back?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.  I wasn't updating the cells I needed correctly. See code below:

```
count = 3
lastIndex = lastRow * 3

ReDim propertyArr(1, lastIndex)
For i = 1 To lastIndex Step 3
        propertyArr(1, i) = originalWS.Cells((count - 1), 5)
        count = count + 1
Next
```